# Error to get variables from text file and use in sh script

Tags: sh

I am currently have a text file, in.txt which consists strings that list input name and coordinate. I need to split the string to get two variables, $name and $coor, then use it in a sh script, test.sh . But i still could not get the expected result and I am not sure if my syntax was wrong but this is what i am roughly doing.

Here is the in.txt:

```
wa_qf 21.39,1.00
cd_lf 90.12,12.21
ab_od 1.22,3.45
zr_df 23.00,0.98
```

Here is the test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read input

directory = /users/maz/test/in.txt
name="$(cut -d' ' -f1 <"$directory")"
coor="$(cut -d' ' -f2 <"$directory")"
do
  {
        echo "The coordinate for input $name : ($coor)"     
  } > /users/maz/test/"$in.log"
done < "$directory"
```

The expected output in file in.log:

```
The coordinate for input wa_qf : (21.39,1.00)
The coordinate for input cd_lf : (90.12,12.21)
The coordinate for input ab_od : (1.22,3.45)
The coordinate for input zr_df : (23.00,0.98)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to write to in.log, you are overwriting the file instead of appending it, so every you go through the loop, you are overwriting your previous line. Instead, do >>... Here is my code, I tested it and it works...

Please note that I am hard coding the file names, you can put them in the variables if you'd like and use the variables...

```
#!/bin/bash

while read inline
do
    name=`echo "$inline" | cut -d' ' -f1`
    coor=`echo "$inline" | cut -d' ' -f2`

    echo "The coordinate for input $name : ($coor)" >> ./in.log
done < ./in.txt
```

Instead, you can also cat the file and pipe the output to while loop too if you'd like...

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ./in.txt | while read inline
do
    name=`echo "$inline" | cut -d' ' -f1`
    coor=`echo "$inline" | cut -d' ' -f2`

    echo "The coordinate for input $name : ($coor)" >> ./in.log
done
```

My in.txt:

```
wa_qf 21.39,1.00
cd_lf 90.12,12.21
ab_od 1.22,3.45
zr_df 23.00,0.98
```

My in.log file after execution:

```
The coordinate for input wa_qf : (21.39,1.00)
The coordinate for input cd_lf : (90.12,12.21)
The coordinate for input ab_od : (1.22,3.45)
The coordinate for input zr_df : (23.00,0.98)
```